# Chrome sees variables before they're defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm not sure if this is a typical behavior. But If I have a script on a page and I set a breakpoint at the first line, all the global variables and functions are viewable(but undefined) on the list of global variables at the right , even though the script hasn't been "read" yet.
Is this the case or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: [Check this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declarations of variables, using `var`, are (like function declarations) *hoisted* so the variables are created when the function is entered.

This is covered in [the language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5).

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the below link for more
http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html